# PrimeNg Calendar not displaying date

Tags: angular, date, calendar, format, primeng

I try to use a p-calendar component from PrimeNg, but it doesn't display my date. The field stays blank.

Retrieved data from spring Backend, json format with Jackson json:
dateExpiration: 4102527600000
So date is in ms since 1970

In my userdetail.component.ts i have:

```
ngOnInit() {
        let id = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params["id"];

        if(id != null) {
            this.userDatasource.getUser(id).subscribe(data => {
                console.log(data.userDTO);
                this.userDetailFormGroup.patchValue(data.userDTO);
            });
        }
    }
```

In my userdetail.component.ts i have:

```
<p-calendar id="dateExpiration" name="dateExpiration" formControlName="dateExpiration" dateFormat="dd/mm/yy" [showIcon]="true"></p-calendar>
```

When i add:

```
this.userDetailFormGroup.get('dateExpiration').patchValue(new Date(data.userDTO.dateExpiration));
```

It works, but can it be done without that last statement? Else i hav to do this for all my date values

Comment: Do you see errors in the console?

Comment: No, no errors in log

Answer (score 0):

PrimeNG Calendar component needs Date object as value, you cannot feed it just number. That's why the "last statement" makes it work, since you create Date object from the number of miliseconds.

Or you need to specify `dateType string` - https://primeng.org/calendar#api.calendar.props.dataType